# Jenkins jelly: refresh hetero-list after selection

Tags: java, jenkins, jelly

I'm developing a Jenkins plugin (v1.555) and I have the following piece of jelly code:

```
<f:entry title="${%Framework Installation}">
    <select class="setting-input" name="toolHome">
        <j:forEach var="inst" items="${descriptor.installations}">
            <f:option selected="${inst.home==instance.toolHome}" 
               value="${inst.home}">${inst.name} (${inst.home})</f:option>
        </j:forEach>
    </select>
</f:entry>

<f:entry title="${%Goals}">
    <f:hetero-list name="extensions" items="${instance.extensions}"
       descriptors="${descriptor.getExtensionDescriptors(instance.toolHome)}"
       hasHeader="true" />
</f:entry>
```

The first *entry* gives me a list of installations from the global configuration from which I should choose one.
The second *entry* is an hetero-list that is intended to provide me a list of descriptors to choose, based on the **toolHome** I've selected above.

It works fine if I select the Installation, save the job and refresh the screen (the **getExtensionDescriptors** method is invoked after every reload).
But what I needed here is to invoke this method and refresh my hetero-list right after I choose the tool.

How should I implement that?

Comment: I've been looking for a way to do this myself.  Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Dan I'm really sorry. I didn't find a solution for this... :-(

Comment: Me either.  Everything I've done requires a refresh.  The page in its entirety pretty much needs to be built from the get go.  Unfortunately this is really limiting.